# Если передать путь с пробелами, argparse пишет unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, cmd, python-2.x, argparse

Есть такой код:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
parser.add_argument('-p',help='Path to file')
args = parser.parse_args()
fp = args.p
print fp
```

Если передать туда -p C:\Program Files (x86)\
. Напишет не признанный аргумент. Как это исправить?

Comment: вопрос не имеет отношения к argparse. Попробуйте `sys.argv` напечатать, чтобы убедиться. Вопрос имеет отношения как аргументы из cmd в python передаются. К примеру, в cmd.exe вам придётся экранировать специальные символы такие как `^` или пробелы (`^` используется в cmd для экранирования других символов, пробелы служат для отделения аргументов друг от друга)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробелы в пути воспринимаются как другие аргументы, поэтому, если пробелы есть нужно значение в кавычки обернуть:

```
-p "C:\Program Files (x86)\"
```

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что эта строчка не в Питоне, а скорее всего в консоли с запущенным cmd.exe